# OneDrive shared link branding or changing layout

Tags: javascript, layout, onedrive, branding

I am currently developing a RESTful based service where I call the OneDrive API to store and retrieve Word documents. I can also generate a so called "shared edit link (shared_edit_link)" or a "shared read link" (shared_read_link) which points to uploaded Word documents and this allows me to give the shared link to anyone so they can edit the Word document. Works great.

When you open the shared edit link you see the OneDrive online Word editor with the document with in the header buttons for signing in and sharing the document to OneDrive.

Question: is it possible to change the layout of the OneDrive Word editor with a custom logo/branding and/or is it possible to remove the buttons for signing in and sharing the document? I would like to only show the document with the Word functionality, preferably nothing related to signing in or sharing to OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

Long answer, what you want sounds like your own online document editor. So, it is certainly possible to get the document content via API and then insert that into your own custom editor that you built. But there is no way to programmatically alter the provided OneDrive/Office Online/Word editor to remove branding, etc.